# Codeigniter Pagination creating extra links?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

My english is not good so sorry for any mistake.I was trying to use codeigniter pagination library , but i am facing a problem it create extra links. My data completes in two pages but there are 4 page links appearing in the bottom when i click on 3rd or 4th link it give error.
Here is my Controller code..

```
 public function usr_list(){
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "usr/usr_list";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->ListModel->record_count();
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $data["results"] = $this->ListModel->getUser($config["per_page"] , $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('userList' , $data);
}
```

That's my Model code

```
function getUser($limit , $start){

    $this->db->select("u_id,name,email,phone,cnic");
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->limit($limit , $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {
    $data[] = $rows;
  }
  return $data;
}
return false;
```

}

In the picture you can see last record is on page 2 but there are 4 links [image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your "record_count" function in the "ListModel" model?

Comment: Change $config["num_links"] = 1; or even 0 as this is the number of pages to show before and after the current page. The actual links are calculated on the total_rows and per_page settings.

Comment: @vivek this is the code of round function:
public function record_count() {

    return $this->db->count_all($this->db->dbprefix . 'attendence');
  }

Comment: @TimBrownlaw by doing this problem is not solving because after 2nd page when i click on next page it still show the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `record_count()` function is returning the number of entries in the 'attendence' table, while the data displayed in the paginated table is from the  'user' table (`getUser` function).
The 'attendence' table probably will be having more records than in the 'user' table which is giving you the extra pagination links.

Change your record_count() function as follows.

```
public function record_count() {
  return $this->db->count_all('user');
}
```